# How to get recordsChanged sync status using JS Datastore API?

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm using the JavaScript SDK flavor of the Dropbox Datastore API with a web app for mobile and desktop. When the `recordsChanged` event fires while the app is offline, object data about those changes are generated but the changes can't sync to the `datastore` until the app is online again.

The event data can be checked against the settings table, for instance, like this:

```
 e.affectedRecordsForTable("settings")
```

But the array data returned has a lot of layers to wade through.

```
 [t_datastore: t_deleted: false_managed_datastore: t_record_cache: t_rid: "startDate"_tid: "settings"__proto__: t]
```

I would like to capture the "has been synced" or the "not yet synced" status of each change (each array index) so that I can store the data still waiting to sync in case the session is lost (user closes the `app/browser` or OS kills the app process).  But I also want to know if/when the data does eventually sync successfully.  Where can I find the property holding this data?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @shivam. I wasn't aware that could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer.  Steve Marx has a post on the Dropbox developer blog that covers the information I needed. There is a `datastore.getSyncStatus().uploading` property that returns `true` or `false` depending on the state of the datastore sync status.

Source:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/61/checking-the-datastore-sync-status-in-javascript